# How to configure exchange 2010 to be used as an external smtp relay?

Tags: exchange-2010, smtp

I'm currently trying to configure our exchange 2010 to be used as a external smtp relay. What I'm trying to do is allow certain websites that we manage to send email using our exchange server smtp relay. I was told that I needed to created a receiver connector under Server Configuration>Hub Transport. After I created the receiver connector I added the following confi in which I added the website IP address in the "Receiver mail from remote servers ect" then unders Authentication I selected Externally Secured,TLS and under permissions I selected exchange servers.

I went to one of our websites and configure it with this configuration and I'm still getting "SMTP connect failed."

Can someone help me? or what is the  proper way to get this to work. Multiple websites are going to be using this exchanger server SMTP relay in a secure way.

Comment: OP, you can help others help you by fully explaining what you've already tried in detail with configuration settings, etc.  As it stands now, you aren't really giving anyone something to go on.  You talk about "Send Connector" which isn't correct for this use anyway.

Comment: Also, be sure and do this RIGHT or you'll end up as an open relay.

Comment: http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/6074/do-you-have-a-checklist-that-can-help-me-ask-a-better-question

Comment: OK I already added more info

Answer (score 1):

You sated that you have created a send connector, if you are allowing a relay through then you want to create a receive connector.

You can use these instructions but I suggest you at least secure it to just the IPs of the servers you control.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb232021%28v=exchg.141%29.aspx

To create a Receive connector on a computer that has the Edge Transport server role installed, select Edge Transport, and then in the work pane, click the Receive Connectors tab.

To create a Receive connector on a Hub Transport server role, in the console tree, expand Server Configuration and select Hub Transport. In the result pane, select the server on which you want to create the connector, and then click the Receive Connectors tab.

```
In the action pane, click New Receive Connector. The New Receive Connector wizard starts.

On the Introduction page, follow these steps:

    In the Name field, type a meaningful name for this connector. This name is used to identify the connector.

    In the Select the intended use for this Receive connector field, select Custom.

    Click Next.

On the Local Network settings page, follow these steps:

    Select the existing All Available IPv4 entry, and then click Remove icon.

    Click Add. In the Add Receive Connector Binding dialog box, select Specify an IP address. Type an IP address assigned to a network adapter on the local server that's best able to communicate with the remote messaging server. In the Port field, type 25, and then click OK. Leave the Specify the FQDN this connector will provide in response to HELO or EHLO field blank.

    Click Next.

On the Remote Network settings page, follow these steps:

    Select the existing 0.0.0.0 - 255.255.255.255 entry, and then click Remove icon.

    Click Add or the drop-down arrow located next to Add and type the IP address or IP address range for the remote messaging server or servers that are allowed to relay mail on this server. When you're finished entering the IP addresses, click OK.

    Click Next.

On the New Connector page, review the configuration summary for the connector. If you want to modify the settings, click Back. To create the Receive connector by using the settings in the configuration summary, click New.

On the Completion page, click Finish.

In the work pane, select the Receive connector that you created.

Under the name of the Receive connector in the action pane, click Properties to open the Properties page.

Click the Permission Groups tab. Select Anonymous users.

Click OK to save your changes and exit the Properties page.
```

Comment: If you selected Anonymous Users, that actually does not allow unauthenticated users to relay off the mail server. You need to use the following command in EMS: `Get-ReceiveConnector “receiveconnectorname” | Add-ADPermission -User “NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON” -ExtendedRights “Ms-Exch-SMTP-Accept-Any-Recipient”`

Comment: +1 for this: `"I suggest you at least secure it to just the IPs of the servers you control."` - the last thing you want is to become an open relay.